# SQL Server : Query To Retrieve a Row based on Value in a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two databases one database is recording tank levels every 1 minute. We have about 30 tanks. The other database contains lookup tables that contain the number of gallons or each tank for a given level.

I have manged to use an `INNER JOIN` to get data from the lookup table in SQL Server 2012

```
WITH T1 As 
(
   SELECT 
       DateTime, TagName, Value 
   FROM 
       INSQL.Runtime.dbo.History 
   WHERE 
       DateTime = (SELECT Max(DateTime) 
                   FROM INSQL.Runtime.dbo.History
                   WHERE TagName LIKE 'LT%') 
       AND TagName LIKE 'LT%' AND Value <> '0'
),
T2 AS 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM TankSTrappingDB.dbo.StrappingTable
)
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.TagName = T2.TagName 
WHERE T2.LIT_PV <= T1.Value
```

However this returns all of the rows from table 2, where the value of the actual level in the tank is less than the value recorded in table 1. I just need the single row from table 2 that is the closest match to the value recorded in table with with the corresponding timestamp.

Comment: Some sample data would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining T2 to T2, you could lookup the MAX(LIT_PV) in T2, where the TAGname matches? But, if you also want other values from the T2 table, you can add another test to the last bit in your SQL

```
   ...   ...
    SELECT * 
    FROM T1 
    LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.TagName = T2.TagName 
    WHERE T2.LIT_PV <= T1.Value

    and T2.LIT_PV in 
     (select max(T2A.LIT_PV) from T2 T2A
      where T1.TagName = T2A.TagName and T2A.LIT_PV <= T1.Value
     )
```

Comment: OK I have 1 more issue, if the Value of LT% is < 0 the Tank does not show up in the result table, is there anyway to set the value to 0 in the result table if the value in T1 < 0 thanks

Comment: If I understand you right, you need to put the whole where clause within parentheses, and then add: "OR T1.Value < 0)"

Comment: thank you, for our response, but I was able to update the a temporary table and set the value to zero if the value recorded was less than zero.  and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query. As the sample data is not available I could not test this query.

```
WITH T1 As 
(
   SELECT 
       DateTime, TagName, Value,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TagName ORDER BY DateTime DESC) RN
   FROM 
       INSQL.Runtime.dbo.History 
   WHERE 
    TagName LIKE 'LT%' AND Value <> '0'
),
T2 AS 
(
   SELECT *,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T.LIT_PV DESC) RN
   FROM TankSTrappingDB.dbo.StrappingTable T
   INNER JOIN T1 ON T1.TagName = T.TagName
    AND T.LIT_PV <= T1.Value
  WHERE T1.RN = 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.TagName = T2.TagName 
AND T1.RN = T2.RN
WHERE T2.RN = 1
```